# Edit text in a file with a script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file called flw.py and would like to write a bash script that will replace some text in the file (take out the last two lines and add two new lines). I apologize if this seems like a stupid question. A thorough explanation would be appreciated since I am still learning to script. Thanks!

Comment: Better you show some examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
head -n -2 flw.py > tmp                      # (1)
echo "your first new line here..." >> tmp    # (2)
echo "your second new line here...." >> tmp  #
mv tmp flw.py                                # (3)
```

Explanation:

1. `head` normally prints out the first ten lines of a file. The `-n` argument can change the number of lines printed out. So if you wanted to print out the first 15 lines you would use `head -n 15`. If you give negative numbers to head it means the opposite: print out all lines but the last N lines. Which happens to be what you want: `head -n -2`

   Then we redirect the output of our `head` command to a temporary file named `tmp`. `>` does the redirecting magic here. `tmp` now contains everything of flw.py but the last two lines.
2. Next we add the two new lines by using the `echo` command. We *append* the output of the `echo "your first new line here..."` to our `tmp` file. `>>` appends to an existing file, whereas `>` will overwrite an existing file.

   We do the same thing for the second line we want to append.
3. Last, we move the `tmp` file to `flw.py` and the job is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single sed command to get you expect result

```
sed -n 'N;$!P;$!D;a\line\n\line2' fly.py
```

**Example:**

```
cat fly.py
1
2
3
4
5

sed -n 'N;$!P;$!D;a\line\n\line2' fly.py
```

**Output :**

```
1
2
3
line1
line2
```

**Note :**
Using `-i` option to update your file